# Android studio: automatically open html test result file generated by './gradlew test'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a few unit tests that are being ran by the command './gradlew test'. When this completes, it generates 'index.html' in the build/reports folder.

Is there a way to have that automatically open when finished?

Thanks

Edit: I can use the command

```
./gradlew test && start C:\\<PACKAGE>\\build\\reports\\tests\\testDebugUnitTest\\debug\\index.html
```

This works. However. Is there a way to just include that entire line in my gradle file so it does it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project `build.gradle` you can add this task:

```
task testAndOpen(type: Exec) {
    //execute test task first
    dependsOn 'test'
    //set the base dir
    workingDir './build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/debug'
    //launch cmd and open the file with the default associated program
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'start index.html'
}
```

then from terminal you can do `.\gradlew testAndOpen`.

If you are not on Windows you can do a similar thing with a bit different commands. This is the "dirty and fast" way, because the path folder must be changed manually for different flavors but it's a good starting point.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying ----

Could not get unknown property 'test' for task ':package:testAndOpen' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.

on the line 'dependsOn test' . ---- Shouldn't test be a predefined task already? ./gradlew test works for me

Comment: In my environment is running fine... if you change `test` with `clean` it runs? yeah test should be ok i think. Reading at the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html) it should be already defined

Comment: I ended up just having to put test in ticks --- dependsOn 'test' and now it compiles and is working correctly. Thank you so much!

Comment: I've updated the answer with your information. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

the task will open all test reports from folder `MyProject/mymodule/build/reports/tests`

just add the code to `mymodule/build.gradle`

and execute in terminal:

```
./gradlew app:testDebugUnitTest --tests com.examplepackage.* testOpenTestReport
```

```
task testOpenTestReport(group: "verification") {
    doLast{
        File reportsDir = new File("${project.buildDir.path}/reports/tests")
        if (!reportsDir.exists() || !reportsDir.isDirectory()) {
            println "reportsDir ${reportsDir.absolutePath} not exist"
            return null
        }

        fileTree(reportsDir)
                .filter { it.isFile() }
                .files
                .findAll { (it.name == "index.html") }
                .forEach{file->
                    println "${file.absolutePath}"
                    //launch cmd and open the file with the default associated program
                    if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains('windows')) {
                        println "start ${file.absolutePath}".execute().text.trim()
                    } else {
                        println "sensible-browser ${file.absolutePath}".execute().text.trim()
                    }
                }
    }
}
```